# Outlook web-add-in doesn't show ribbon button for message read

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I've developed an Outlook web add-in (based in the Office JS API)that shows a ribbon button in the Outlook MessageRead window to open it our webapp in the sidebar.
This add-in works fine so far on Outlook Web and Outlook Desktop.
However, in the Outlook Desktop, if I open an email from a local Outlook data file (.pst) the ribbon button isn't shown. I noticed that other add-ins, like by example InSights aren't also shown on that window.

Are the Outlook web add-ins not supported for local Outlook data file? I didn't find any mention about that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Office Add-ins can be run for Exchange accounts where they are deployed. I'd suggest posting a suggestion to the user voice forum to request a feature to support other stores in Outlook. See the [Office Developer suggestion box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) for more information.